# slick 3 mapping custom fields

Tags: scala, slick-3.0, frm

I have case class with a lot of fields

```
 case class H(     
                           id: Int, 
                           min: Option[String] = None,
                           max: Option[String] = None,
                           step: Option[String] = None,
                           ...
                           )
```

How can I map a few field to the table?

```
class TH(tag: Tag) extends Table[H](tag, "H") {
  def id = column[Long]("ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def min = column[Option[String]]("M")

  def * = (id, min) <>(H.tupled, H.unapply)
}
```

when I tried like this -   `def * = (id, min) <>(H.tupled, H.unapply)` , instead of map all fields, got compilation exception. Can I map custom field to the table ?

BR!

Answer (score 2):

`tupled` and `unapply` are just basics function generated by the case class which define the following functions (among other things) with all the fields of the case class.

For example, for a case class `X(a: A, b: B, c: C, d: D)`, you have:

```
def tupled(a: a, b: b, c: c, d: d): X
def unapply(x: X): Option[(A, B, C, D)]
```

In other hand, your projection constructed with `<>` expects parameters: `(f: (U => R), g: (R => Option[U]))`, where `U` is the combinaison of your fields type.

You're not tied to use the "automatic" tupled/unapply if they don't match your needs, you can provides your own definition:

```
class TH(tag: Tag) extends Table[H](tag, "H") {
  def id = column[Long]("ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def min = column[Option[String]]("M")

  def * = (id, min) <> (
    { tuple: (Long, Option[String]) => TH(id, min) },
    { th: TH => Some((th.id, th.min)) }
  )
}
```